# stack double linked list in C

Tags: c, stack, doubly-linked-list

so i get home work to make stack with double linked list in C is this already correct,
or something missing in my code ?
i feel like something is missing but idk what is it still confuse about doubly linked list

```
int length = 0;

struct NODE {
    char name[100];
    int weight;
    
    NODE *next, *prev;
}*head=NULL, *tail=NULL;

void cls() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++) {
        printf("\n");
    }
}

NODE* createNode(char name[], int weight) {
    NODE* temp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    strcpy(temp->name, name);
    temp->weight = weight;
    temp->next = temp->prev = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void pushHead(char name[], int weight) {
    NODE* temp = createNode(name, weight);
    if(head==NULL) {
        head = temp;
        head = tail = temp;
    } else {
        temp->next= head;
        head->prev = temp;
        head = temp;
    }
    length++;
}

void popHead() {
    if(!head) {
        printf("no data");
    } else {
        if(head->next == NULL && tail->prev ==NULL) {
            free(head);
            head = tail = NULL;
        } else {            
            NODE *temp = head;
            head = head->next;
            head ->prev = NULL;
            free(temp);
        }
        length--;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*is this already correct, or something missing in my code*". The way to answer that is to write and run comprehensive test cases. Have you done that? What did you find?

Comment: @kaylum already run the code its run fine can pop and push just fine, my teacher instruction just so simple make program about stack with double linked list in c, without giving other explanation and example

Comment: "*can pop and push just fine*". But are you happy and confident with the level of testing you have done? If yes, then there is no need to ask this question. If not then write and run more comprehensive tests. You can't turn to others to verify your code for you all the time so you need to develop the necessary skills and tools to do that on your own.

Comment: don;t see the purpose of `tail` in a stack?  just push and pop to/from the top.

Comment: You fail to set temp->prev.

Comment: @AndersK so you dont need tail in stack ? ok noted,

Comment: @500-InternalServerError oh its incorrect ? i look up at example from ppt provide by my school its set like that for doubly linked list

Comment: tail is only useful if you want append nodes since then you don't need to find the last element and then add - like with a linked list. with a LIFO you just interface with `head`.  when you `pophead` just check what the top node points to, if it has a next then just set head to point to that. `tmp = head; head = head->next; free(tmp)`. the prev you don't need to bother with, in fact prev is not needed for the stack since you are only interested in the head node.